# Can't load file (doesn't open) Display Data +ContentOpenable using ACTION_VIEW intent in android

Tags: java, android

In  my Android app, I am downloading pdf on button click in users mobile external storage(download directory). Once downloaded I am giving option to open the file and allowing user to choose among pdf viewers available usin ActionView Intent.Below is my code -

```
val uri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(binding.root.context,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",Storage.getFile("${fileName}.pdf"))

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                     
binding.root.context.startActivity(intent)
```

This is working fine when user open the file inital few times but after that file dosen't open. Getting below error:
Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : 0.Paper 1.pdf] +ContentOpenable, uri: content://com.applications.koushik.ugcnetpractice.fileprovider/external_files/Download/0.Paper%201.pdf, has subtitles: false
Error getting package info: com.applications.koushik.ugcnetpractice

Checked that file exsist in the location also able to open it directly.

Below is my Provider tag from Mainifest file:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.applications.koushik.ugcnetpractice.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
     android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
     android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Here is my provider_paths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: This error makes no sense. You should be able to use ACTION_VIEW a hundred times. Which pdf viewer app is chosen by the user?

Comment: Pdf reader app is being used to open the pdf, it opens the pdf but with blank page nothing shows up there. I've tried other apps as well but its the same behavior.

Comment: ??? That does not match: `This is working fine when user open the file inital few times but`.

Comment: yes initial few times it loads perfectly with proper content.. after few times or a day after when we try it shows blank page

Comment: That makes no sense. Well read my first comment..

Comment: @Neerajvishwakarma did u find any solution for this?

Comment: @SandeepYohans No solution yet but I WPS Office is able to open that pdf.